# Setting up angular unit test on directive that links to external DOM element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing

This is my test set-up. I'm adding two elements to the $document, and want them to be available to my directive for testing

```
beforeEach(inject(function ($compile, $rootScope, $document) {
   var scope = $rootScope.$new();
   var element = $compile('<div id="inputId"></div>')(scope);
   var myDirective = $compile('<div my-directive my-directive-attr="inputId"></div>')(scope)
   angular.element($document[0].body).append(element);
   angular.element($document[0].body).append(myDirective);
   scope.$digest();
});
```

This is part of my directive below. I'm trying to reference the element on the $document based on the ID passed to the directive attribute.

```
angular.module('myModule',[])
.directive('myDirective', function ($document) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
      var inputId = attrs.myDirectiveAttr;
      var fromDocument = $document[0].getElementById(inputId);
      console.log(fromDocument);
    };
  });
```

The console log is picking up null in the directive. Is the only way to have elements within the $document to mock the entire $document service?

Comment: You don't append it anywhere, of courser it's `null`.

Comment: @dfsq If I append it directly to the dom using something like angular.element($document[0].body).append(elem), will it be available when $document is injected elsewhere (i.e. my actual directive code)?

Comment: @Blake Yes, it should works. But do not forget to remove the element from the $document in an `afterEach()` block, otherwise it will polute the document and may affect other testcases.

Comment: @runTarm I've updated the question based on your responses. However, inside the directive, my log is picking up null.

Comment: I wonder why your directive has get compiled. It should be `<div my-directive my-directive-attr="inputId" ..`. You might also have to append the inputId element before compiling your directive.

Comment: Thanks @runTarm , that was a syntax error in my question write-up. I've updated it.

Comment: Have you tried appending the inputId element before compiling the myDirective?

Comment: @runTarm The ordering is what was the important clue here. I added a full solution below. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this. The order of adding elements to the $document and $compiling is crucial here.

The problem with the initial code is that the $compile of the myDirective element happened after the element was added to the $document. The correct test code would be -

```
beforeEach(inject(function ($compile, $rootScope, $document) {
  var scope = $rootScope.$new();
  var element = $compile('<div id="inputId"></div>')(scope);
  angular.element($document[0].body).append(element);      
  var myDirective = $compile('<div my-directive my-directive-attr="inputId"></div>')(scope);
});
```

The code in the 'link' method is triggered as the myDirective element is compiled. Thus we needed to ensure that the initial element has already been added to the $document before we call $compile. This assures 'element' to be available during the link phase of the directive.

As an aside, note that for testing purposes, the myDirective element doesn't actually need to be added to $document.